# How to send data to database on click?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a button which opens up a modal with some text inside. Every button is associated to an `id` of a mail.
In the database, `mailbox->read`, the value is `0` by default, which means it is unread. I want to send the value `1` to `mailbox->read` at click on the modal, which means it's read.

How can I do that?

Here is my view:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$key+1}}">
<i class="icon-eye" style="color: white"></i>
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div  @if ($key === 0)  @endif  class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$key+1}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          {{$inbox->pivot->message}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
public function mailbox()
    {
        if ($user = Sentinel::check())
        {
            $data = $this->data;
            $id = $user->id;

            $data['users'] = User::findOrfail($id);

            $data['title'] = 'Mailbox';

            if(\Session::get('tabname') != "")
                {
                    $data['tabname'] = \Session::get('tabname');
                }else{
                    $data['tabname'] = "inbox";
                }
            return view('mailbox.mailbox',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method in your controller and sent data using `ajax request`.

template:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs js-read" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$key+1}}">
<i class="icon-eye" style="color: white"></i>
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div  @if ($key === 0)  @endif  class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$key+1}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          {{$inbox->pivot->message}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/set-read',[
    'uses' => 'Controller@ajaxSetRead'
]);
```

Controller:

```
public function ajaxSetRead()
    {
        $buttonId = INPUT::get('buttonId');
        ...
    }
```

JS file:

```
$('.js-read').on('click', function (e) {
$.ajax({
    url     : '/set-read',
    method  : 'post',
    data    : {
        buttonId  : this.data('target')
    },
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success : function(response){

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must fire an event on modal opening event ;
you can access modal opening event like follow :

```
$("#exampleModal{{$key+1}}").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
   alert("just before modal open");

   var hostAPI = "yourdomain.dev/mail/seen/{{$key+1}}";
   $.get( hostAPI, function( data ) {
     console.log("now you can change row style to seen type.");
   });
});
```

then you need to create a route for turn 'seen' from 0 to 1;

```
Route::get('mail/seen/{id}', 'YourController@updateSeenStatus')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

after al you must change record in updateSeenStatus; thats all. hope this works.

Comment: Hi!So, I need to make a `updateSeenStatus` public function in my controller?